# Скопировать ворд файл и изменить скопированный файл

Tags: c#, ms-word

Я хочу скопировать ворд файл и в скопированном файле изменить определенный текст. Как это сделать используя C#?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WordOperation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string _text;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
        private void FindAndReplace(WordOperation.Application doc, object findText, object replaceWithText)
        {
            object matchCase = false;
            object matchWholeWord = true;
            object matchWildCards = false;
            object matchSoundsLike = false;
            object matchAllWordForms = false;
            object forward = true;
            object format = false;
            object matchKashida = false;
            object matchDiacritics = false;
            object matchAlefHamza = false;
            object matchControl = false;
            object read_only = false;
            object visible = true;
            object replace = 2;
            object wrap = 1;
            doc.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
                ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //Нам нужно что бы этот метод сработал
            copyFile();
            changeFileContext();
        }

        public void changeFileContext()
        {
            object fileName = Path.Combine(@"E:\test2.docx");
            WordOperation.Application wordApp = new WordOperation.Application { Visible = false };
            WordOperation.Document aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
            aDoc.Activate();

            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "adx", textBox1.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "soyadx", textBox2.Text);
            aDoc.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Mətn dəyişdirildi");
        }
        public void copyFile()
        {
            var wordApp = new WordOperation.Application();
            WordOperation.Document documentFrom = null, documentTo = null;

            try
            {
                var fileNameFrom = @"E:\test.docx";

                wordApp.Visible = true;

                documentFrom = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileNameFrom, Type.Missing, true);
                WordOperation.Range oRange = documentFrom.Content;
                oRange.Copy();

                var fileNameTo = @"E:\test2.docx";
                documentTo = wordApp.Documents.Add();
                documentTo.Content.PasteSpecial(DataType: WordOperation.WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting);
                documentTo.SaveAs(fileNameTo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                if (documentFrom != null)
                    documentFrom.Close(false);

                if (documentTo != null)
                    documentTo.Close();

                if (wordApp != null)
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);

                wordApp = null;
                documentFrom = null;
                documentTo = null;

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Имхо, я бы добавил в текст несколько слов, что в программе не получается.

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста